# Github - use one repo as basis for another, preserving branches and history

Tags: git, github, git-clone

I'd like to move over a repo, with all its history and branches, to a fresh repo. I've been able to find ways to use a single branch as a basis for a new repo ([git workflow - using one repo as the basis for another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096448/git-workflow-using-one-repo-as-the-basis-for-another)), but I can't figure out how I'd preserve all branches (and their histories, ideally). Is there a way to do this? or possibly a clever workaround so I don't lose my work on non-master branches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clone a fresh copy of your repo, using the --mirror flag:

```
$ git clone --mirror git://example.com/some-big-repo.git
```

This is a bare repo, which means your normal files won't be visible, but it is a **full** copy of the Git database of your repository, including all branches. Once cloned, set the origin to be your new repo, and push:

```
$ git remote set-url origin git://new.com/some-big-repo.git
$ git push
```

All branches will be transferred, and this method will work for any Git host, not just GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply fork the repository on Github, which will make a complete copy of it as well as link the copy to the original for the purposes of generating pull requests to it.