# What is the proper git workflow for basing a project off a 'seed' repo?

Tags: git, github

As an example: suppose you have a personal project like Angular Seed (which is a starting point for an Angular project https://github.com/angular/angular-seed).

Now you want to use that as a starting point for a project (say an online photo album).

You shouldn't just create a branch because you're not making a variation of the seed project.
But github won't let you fork it if it's your own repo.

So what is the workflow to create a clone that can still pull in changes form the original seed project? I thought that was a fork.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git workflow - using one repo as the basis for another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096448/git-workflow-using-one-repo-as-the-basis-for-another)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the right answer here is to use something like Yeoman Generators. (http://yeoman.io/) You want to use the git repo with your seed project as a generator. It wouldn't allow you to continually pull in changes from the seed project though.

The solution of using two remotes works, but eventually the projects will diverge enough that will make keeping those projects in synch very difficult.

Comment: I think my own answer gives me a more immediate solution. Though I think moving forward using something like Yeoman is the pragmatic approach. So I'll mark yours as correct. Thanks.

Comment: This is definitely better way to do over cloning, because you don't need the seed repo's history to pollute your real changes, nor do you normally need to merge changes from the seed repo to yours.

Answer (score 28):

I just found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/4096529/131227 as well as a comment ([git workflow - using one repo as the basis for another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096448/git-workflow-using-one-repo-as-the-basis-for-another?rq=1#comment4409551_4096529)) which together lead me to a solution I like.

`git clone -o boilerplate ssh://git@github.com/user/proj.git new_proj`
The -o boilerplate renames the origin to `boilerplate` which can still be used to pull changes from.

Create your new empty github new_proj repo.
Then
`git remote add origin ssh://git@github.com/user/new_proj.git`

Comment: Now I get it. Just for sake of completeness, note that you can also just clone, then in the clone add the new remote (your second command), and remove the old with `git remote rm origin`.

Comment: This is what I would do.. though it's easy enough to just clone in the normal way then rename the remote origin later.

So, first you would 
"git clone https://github.com/xxx/seed.git" then "git remote rename origin seed". Later on I could "git remote add" a new origin (per instructions on github.com for example) to enable default push to my own repo. This way I can always pull down from 'upstream' (which is recommended, for example here. https://github.com/firebase/angularFire-seed/tree/master)

Answer (score 4):

What you could do is:

- initialize a new repo
- reference your angular repo as a **[submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/ch6-6.html)** of that new repo
- push that new repo in your GitHub space.

That way, your new project has:

- a subfolder representing your seed project (which you don't modify)
- all your data specific to your project.

---

> My issue with that is that a seed project isn't a library. It doesn't live in a subdirectory of a project. It IS the project when you start, and you build from there.

Then a simple clone that you push back to your new repo is enough.
But that won't keep any "fork" relationship between your two GitHub repos.
You will have to pull one and push to the other through a *local* clone.

Comment: This is what I would do. Seed is basically a dependency, and that's what a submodule is. As a submodule in your photo album project, you can reference it locally, and govern its existence and whereabouts. Also, if you (or anyone) changes seed, you can branch, pull in the latest from seed there, fix any failing tests against that, and merge back in the updated usage to the mainline.

Comment: @GaryFixler yes, I do that all the time, when I don't want to get a full copy of a project in my repo, while still being able to reference  it. For instance: https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything references  https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI

Comment: Thanks @VonC. My issue with that is that a seed project isn't a library. It doesn't live in a subdirectory of a project. It IS the project when you start, and you build from there.

Comment: I see now. I was thinking you might just want to clone into a different name (`git clone <url> <newname>`), but wasn't thinking about the connection to the original.

Answer (score 3):

### Option 1: clone / fetch / merge

Clone the `master` branch of the seed project of your choice, for example:

```
$ git clone -o react-starter-kit -b master --single-branch \
      https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit.git MyApp
$ cd MyApp
```

Down the road, you can pull and merge updates from the seed project back into your local repo by running:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git fetch react-starter-kit
$ git merge react-starter-kit/master
$ npm install
```

### Option 2: clone / pull / diff

Clone the seed project and remove its version history:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit --depth=1
$ git clone https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit MyApp --depth=1
$ cd MyApp
$ rm -rf .git
```

Then, whenever you need to pull the latest updates from the seed project back into your local repo, you can navigate to the original seed project, pull the updates (`git pull`), then compare that folder with your project's folder by using some good Diff tool (e.g. Beyond Compare) that allows you to save and customize folder comparison sessions.

Answer (score 1):

I found mirroring the boilerplate according to [this article](https://help.github.com/articles/duplicating-a-repository/%20test) the only way to work for me:

Clone boilerplate and create new project:

```
git clone --mirror https://github.com/mxstbr/react-boilerplate.git
cd react-boilerplate.git
git remote set-url --push origin https://github.com/gitUser/newProject
```

Update the new project with changes from the boilerplate:

```
cd react-boilerplate.git
git fetch -p origin
git push --mirror
```