# How to pull a different remote branch and merge conflicts

Tags: git, git-remote, boilerplate

I've used a [seed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37661469/1480453) to start my project and added changes, first by cloning the seed project, making edits and changing that `remote` from `origin` to `boilerplate`, now that I've gotten the project to work on master I added my own repo remote. But I want to have a branch for the newer version of the project and the boilerplate repo already has a remote branch `phaser3` that I want to basically pull and replace conflicts so that I can begin migrating to the new release. heres what I tried:

```
➜  dir git:(master) git fetch boilerplate phaser3
From https://github.com/lean/phaser-es6-webpack
 * branch            phaser3    -> FETCH_HEAD
➜  dir git:(master) git checkout phaser3
Branch 'phaser3' set up to track remote branch 'phaser3' from 'boilerplate'.
Switched to a new branch 'phaser3'
➜  dir git:(phaser3) git pull
Already up to date.
```

```
➜  dir git:(phaser3) git pull --rebase
Already up to date.
Current branch phaser3 is up to date.
```

So it seems clear to me that I've gotten my local `phaser3` branch to track `boilerplate/phaser3`, but how do I now pull in the updated phaser3 `package.json` and other files that are different between the two phaser3 branches?

Comment: What's the output of `git status`?

Comment: My point is that there doesn't seem to be any difference. What makes you think there is? You've checked out the branch you want.

Comment: dir git:(phaser3) git status
On branch phaser3
Your branch is up to date with 'boilerplate/phaser3'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean

Comment: the master branch I checked out originally has support for Phaser2, on the github repo's readme it specifies the branch phaser3 for the newer version and navigating to that branch shows it is: "This branch is 5 commits ahead, 32 commits behind master." 

This makes me think that there should be some file changes between the two boilerplate branches and I want to grab those and pull them into my local phaser3 branch

Comment: There probably *are* changes between `phaser2` and `phaser3`, but why do you think there's a diff between `phaser3` and `boilerplate/phaser3`?

Comment: Try this: `git diff phaser3 boilerplate/phaser3`.

Comment: @isherwood that is the problem - there isn't actually a diff here but I expect one as I've moved from my master tracking    boilerplate/master to a new local branch tracking    boilerplate/phaser3 ,  but I cannot seem to get my hands on 
   boilerplate/phaser3 and there is no difference per git status. I could have either misconfigured or missed a step but what I expect to be and what is in the repo are different.

Comment: re: Try this: ```git diff phaser3 boilerplate/phaser3|cat```

I get a long empty output and piping it to cat results in nothing

Comment: My guess is that you have a misunderstanding about what you should be seeing. Have you looked at the actual codebase for the changes?

Comment: @isherwood yes, I am sure it is a misunderstanding and I am not sure where to start. The actual codebase has clear and plain changes even in the package.json that I'd expect to prompt my local git instance to detect a mismatch and allow me to trigger a merge. [link to boilerplate](https://github.com/lean/phaser-es6-webpack/tree/phaser3)

Comment: Your question description is a little hard to follow. There's some ambiguity in what's where. You might revise to remove anything not strictly relevant and clarify a bit. Judging by the lack of response on a  popular topic I'm not the only one fuzzy on the issue.

Comment: @isherwood you're probably right, I am confused as well and I don't know how to clarify which part is the issue and what's not relevant. This is what typically happens when I go off the beaten path with git, then I just end up cloning multiple instances and cut and pasting until it works.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be nothing *wrong* here.  Still, there's something *slightly* suspicious in your output, that suggests that maybe you're running Git version 1.8.3 or earlier, or maybe not.  (You can check, easily, with `git --version`.  If your Git is pre-2.0 it's probably time to upgrade.  The current release is v2.21 as of this answer.)

The interesting part is this bit:

> ```
> ➜  dir git:(master) git fetch boilerplate phaser3
> From https://github.com/lean/phaser-es6-webpack
>  * branch            phaser3    -> FETCH_HEAD
> ```

Compare this to what I get when I `git fetch origin master` in my Linux repository this afternoon:

```
$ git fetch origin master
remote: Counting objects: 235, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (160/160), done.
remote: Total 235 (delta 120), reused 124 (delta 71)
Receiving objects: 100% (235/235), 273.62 KiB | 230.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (120/120), done.
From git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux
 * branch                      master     -> FETCH_HEAD
   9e98c678c2d6..54c490164523  master     -> origin/master
```

Besides the extra verbosity (counting, compressing, receiving, etc.), the last two lines are different in a very important way:

```
 * branch                      master     -> FETCH_HEAD
   9e98c678c2d6..54c490164523  master     -> origin/master
```

They show that my Git has written a new hash ID to `origin/master`.  Specifically, *before* I ran `git fetch` I got:

```
$ git rev-parse origin/master
9e98c678c2d6ae3a17cb2de55d17f69dddaa231b
```

*After* I ran `git fetch`, I got:

```
$ git rev-parse origin/master
54c490164523de90c42b1d89e7de3befe3284d1b
```

This is because `git fetch origin master` updated *two* crucial items in my own Git repository.  One of them is my *remote-tracking name*, `refs/remotes/origin/master`, commonly abbreviated `origin/master`.  The other one is the special file `.git/FETCH_HEAD`, which `git fetch` always writes based on what you told it to fetch and what it got from the other Git.

Your output shows your Git only updating *one* of these items, namely the file `.git/FETCH_HEAD`.  But this could be normal and *not* a sign of an old version of Git, because if I re-run the *same* `git fetch` immediately afterward, this happens:

```
$ git fetch origin master
From git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux
 * branch                      master     -> FETCH_HEAD
```

and that looks the same as your own output.  So I suspect that your `git fetch` did essentially nothing, just like my *second* `git fetch`, because there was nothing to do.  That would lead to the rest of the behavior you're seeing.

#### What's going on here

The key to understanding what's going on—what `git fetch` is doing—lies in realizing that *branch names are not very important to Git*.  What *is* important to Git is each *commit*.  Each commit is uniquely identified by its *hash ID*, which looks random, but is actually a cryptographic checksum of its contents.

A Git commit stores a snapshot of all files, along with some metadata—some data *about* the commit.  The metadata includes the name and email address of whoever made the commit, *when* they made it (a time-stamp), *why* they made it (their log message), and—crucially—the commit's *parent hash ID*.

Here's an example commit from this particular repository.  Its hash ID is `d1f0301b3333eef5efbfa1fe0f0edbea01863d5d`:

```
$ git cat-file -p d1f0301b3333eef5efbfa1fe0f0edbea01863d5d | sed 's/@/ /'
tree 86c897e94952090eee579ed47f49cc7006c41fd6
parent 6b4703768268d09ac928c64474fd686adf4574f9
author Thomas Gleixner <tglx linutronix.de> 1533300299 +0200
committer Thomas Gleixner <tglx linutronix.de> 1533302341 +0200

genirq: Make force irq threading setup more robust

The support of force threading interrupts which are set up with both a
primary and a threaded handler wreckaged the setup of regular requested
threaded interrupts (primary handler == NULL).

[snip]
```

This isn't the way we usually look at commits—most of the time, we might use `git show` or `git log`, for instance, and those *compare* commits to earlier commits so that we can see what's different in the two snapshots.  That's like comparing how warm or rainy it is today to how warm or rainy it was yesterday: it tells us what *changed*, which is sometimes more important to us than the absolute state.  But this does show exactly what's in the commit: it has a *tree* (with some internal Git hash ID), a *parent* with another commit's hash ID, and the author and committer and log message.  (Some commits have more stuff.)  The tree is how Git stores the snapshot.  The `parent` line tells us which commit comes *before* this commit.

The result is that given some Git commit hash ID, Git can always find the commit that comes *before* that commit.  In effect, the parent line *points to* another, earlier commit.  So if we have some long chain of commits:

```
... <-F <-G <-H ...
```

we can pick one of these commits and follow its arrow backwards to the *previous* commit: from `H` to `G`, and then to `F`, and so on.

The problem here is that these hash IDs *appear* totally random, and depend in part on what time, to the exact second, someone made them.  Thomas Gleixner made the commit above at time `1533300299 +0200`, for instance.<sup>1</sup>  All of that detail goes into the commit hash ID.  What this means is that we have no way to know what the hash ID will be—it's *effectively* random.  So how will we know which commit is the *latest* commit?

The answer is that Git helps us out by letting *us* create *branch names*.  We tell Git: *store the **newest / latest** commit's hash ID under some name like `master` or `phaser3`*.  Given the *ID*, Git can find the *commit itself*.  That commit stores a parent ID, so Git can find the parent as well.  The parent stores another parent ID—the grandparent, as it were, of this commit—so Git can find the grandparent, and that commit stores another parent ID, and so on through history.

History, in fact, is nothing more than the set of commits found by going from each commit to its parent(s).  The commits visited, from some set of starting points and working backwards, *are* the history in the Git repository.  The starting points are all the *names* in the repository: branch names, tag names like `v2.1`, and *remote-tracking names* like `origin/master` or `boilerplate/phaser3`.<sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>Well, that's when he *authored* the (original version of the) commit, but then later he *committed* the commit at 1533302341, 34 minutes and 2 seconds later.

<sup>2</sup>A repository can, and after various operations like `git rebase` or `git commit --amend` *will*, contain commits that *aren't* visited by this *walk all the commits reachable by starting at some name* process.  These leftover or junk commits are eventually cleaned up and thrown out by Git's *garbage collector*, `git gc`.  Note that `git gc` does a lot of other housekeeping and performance-improving things, or things intended to improve performance, at least.  It's all done automatically—there is no need to run it manually, normally.

---

#### Checkout creates branches, sometimes

You ran `git checkout phaser3` and your Git said this:

> ```
> Branch 'phaser3' set up to track remote branch 'phaser3' from 'boilerplate'.
> Switched to a new branch 'phaser3'
> ```

Normally, when you say `git checkout somebranch`, what Git does is look around in *your* repository for *your* branch named *`somebranch`*.  That branch name identifies the *newest / latest* commit that should be considered the *tip* of the branch.  Your Git extracts that commit into your index and work-tree, so that you can see it and work with it.

Sometimes, though, you tell Git to check out a branch and *you do not have that branch*.  Instead of just failing—which can still happen:

```
$ git checkout nosuchbranch
error: pathspec 'nosuchbranch' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

—your Git starts out by listing your own branches, a la `git branch`:

```
$ git branch
* master
```

The name you asked for isn't in the list, but Git is not yet ready to give up.  Now it checks all of your *remote-tracking names*, which you can list with `git branch -r`.  The result of this depends on which *remotes* you have—most people have just one, named `origin`, in their repositories—and which *names* your Git remembers *from* those remotes:

```
$ git branch -r
  origin/develop
  origin/feature2
  origin/master
  upstream/master
  upstream/develop
```

I asked for `nosuchbranch` and none of these look like that.  But what if I asked for, say, `feature2`?

Git would scan through these and there would be **exactly one** name matching `feature2`, namely `origin/feature2`.  So my Git would say: *Aha, you want me to **create a new `feature2`** using `origin/feature2` as the commit!*  And now I might have:

```
... <-H <-I <-J   <-- feature2 (HEAD), origin/feature2
```

with names `feature2` and `origin/feature2` *both* remembering the hash ID of commit `J`.

Note that in this particular situation—where I don't have a `develop` but both `origin` *and* `upstream` have one—if I run:

```
git checkout develop
```

my Git will give up, because it doesn't know if it should make a new `develop` from `origin/develop`, or from `upstream/develop`.  Even if those both identify the *same* commit—say, commit `L` that I haven't drawn in the diagram here—my Git doesn't know which of those two to use as the *upstream* setting for my new `develop`.  What I can do here instead is:

```
git checkout --track origin/develop
```

which tells my Git: *Using `origin/develop`, make a new `develop` where `develop` updates from, and pushes to, `origin`'s `develop`.*

We've gone very fast here and not detailed precisely *how* all this works, but I'll mention again here that this sets the *upstream* setting of the newly created branch.  The upstream of a branch is how Git decides to say "ahead" and/or "behind" when you run `git status`, and how Git knows which commits to use if you run `git merge` or `git rebase` with no arguments.  The upstream dictates what `git pull` or `git push` will do if you don't give extra arguments, and which remote `git fetch` will use when you have more than one remote.  So the upstream setting is pretty useful.

#### Summary

`git pull --rebase` is doing nothing because there are no new commits: your graph looks like this, when drawn the way I like to draw commits on StackOverflow:

```
...--G--H   <-- phaser3 (HEAD), boilerplate/phaser3
```

or perhaps like this:

```
...--G--H   <-- boilerplate/phaser3
         \
          I   <-- phaser3
```

The job that `git rebase` does is to *copy* commits that you have that they don't—such as commit `I` in this diagram—to new commits that come after their last commit.  In this case, that would be *copy `I` to a new commit that comes just after `H` instead of where `I` is now*, but `I` is already just after `H`, so there's no need to do any such copying.  (And in the situation where both names point to the *same* commit `H`, there is no commit to copy, which also means there is no work to do.)

The *upstream* of `phaser3` is `boilerplate/phaser3`.  The name `boilerplate` by itself is—usually—just a short name for `https://github.com/lean/phaser-es6-webpack`; Git calls that a *remote*.

There is a complete Git repository over at [`https://github.com/lean/phaser-es6-webpack`](https://github.com/lean/phaser-es6-webpack); it has four branches of its own.  Your repository has copied its `phaser3` branch—the hash ID `c9584e75521a3b94d4f883a246aad134b83dc12d` stored in that name, that is—into your own *remote-tracking* name, `boilerplate/phaser3`.

The `git fetch` and `git push` commands are the ones that transfer commits from one repository to another.  In general, the sender sends commits that the receiver doesn't have yet, so that in the end, the receiver has everything the sender has, plus maybe more if it already had things the sender doesn't have.  Having sent commits from sender to receiver, the receiver now needs to update some *name or names* to remember the new commits.

When using `git fetch`, the receiver—you!—or rather, your Git—updates your *remote-tracking names*.  You take their name, `phaser3`, and prefix it with your remote name, `boilerplate`, and stick a slash in between.  That gives you `boilerplate/phaser3` as a way to remember their commit.

When using `git push`, the sender—you again—is responsible for asking the receiver to set some name in the receiver.  *You* choose what name you ask them to set.  If that name is, say, `phaser3`, you're asking them to *change* **their** `phaser3`.  They do not have a remote-tracking name: there is no `quantum_spaghetti/phaser3` here.  You're asking them to change *their* name.  So in general, you should make sure that whatever new commits you sent them, those new commits have their existing commits as part of the history.